# I can not call an object from one function to another

Tags: php

I have the following code but I can not print the object name:

```
   <?php
       class persons {
         public function people(){ //__construct OR persons to class define constructor 
               $this->name="pepe";
         }

         public function print_1(){
                echo $this->name;
                echo '<br>';
         }
    }

    $per1=new persons();
    $per1->print_1();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you got fatal error because `print` is reserved keyword, you can't use as class `method` name, use another name, see below

```
<?php
       class persons {
         var $name = "";

         public function people(){ 
               $this->name="pepe";
         }

         public function print_1(){
                echo $this->name;
                echo '<br>';
         }
    }

    $per1=new persons();
    $per1->people();
    $per1->print_1();
    ?>
```

As @deceze mention in an comment `__construct()` or `ClassName` method for class construct to initialize values

## DEMO

Comment: I do not print anything

Comment: Thank you again, check my update is as you indicate me but does not work constructor and I do not want to use a constructor!

Comment: ohh, you have updated question.. if you don't want to class class constructor then you will need to call `people` method first see demo link https://eval.in/190569

Comment: @Juan *Why* don't you want to use a constructor and what *do* you want then?

Comment: Not that I would rather want to know what my big mistake, I do not like to stay with doubts

Answer (score 1):

Your `init` function is never executed, hence the name is never set.
If you meant to use a constructor, [you need to name it `__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

(The other error about the reserved `print` keyword applies as well.)

Comment: Ok but I do not want contructor and rename and methods for initializing and printed

Comment: Then you need to call `->init()` at some point. You can't not use a constructor and also not call the code that sets your name but still expect the name to be set.